# SQL: Aggregations over partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, window-functions

Query: Considering only Italian routes, for each category of goods and for each year

- select the average daily income for each month
- the total monthly income since the beginning of the year

SQL:

```
SELECT
  gc.GoodCategory,
  tm.Month,
  tm.Year,
  SUM(ro.Income) / COUNT(DISTINCT tm.Date),
  SUM(ro.Income) OVER (PARTITION BY gc.GoodCategory, tm.Year 
    ORDER BY tm.Month ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)

FROM FactRoutes ro,
     DimLocation dp,
     DimLocation ds,
     DimGoodCategory gc,
     DimTime tm

WHERE ro.DepartureID = dp.LocationID
    AND ro.DestinationID = ds.LocationID
    AND ro.GoodCategoryID = gc.GoodCategoryID
    AND ro.GoodTimeID = tm.GoodTimeID
    AND dp.State = 'Italy'
    AND ds.State = 'Italy'

GROUP BY gc.GoodCategory,
     tm.Month,
     tm.Year;
```

But facing the below error

```
Column 'FactRoutes.Income' is invalid in the select list
because it is not contained in either an aggregate function
or the GROUP BY clause.
```

whats the better way to handle it?

Comment: Are you familiar with `JOIN`  Is there a reason you are not using proper syntax?

Comment: I believe the engine does choose the inner joins internally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
SELECT
  gc.GoodCategory,
  tm.Month,
  tm.Year,
  SUM(ro.Income) / COUNT(DISTINCT tm.Date),
  SUM(SUM(ro.Income)) OVER (PARTITION BY gc.GoodCategory, tm.Year ORDER BY tm.Month)
FROM FactRoutes ro
INNER JOIN DimLocation dp ON ro.DepartureID = dp.LocationID
INNER JOIN DimLocation ds ON ro.DestinationID = ds.LocationID
INNER JOIN DimGoodCategory gc ON ro.GoodCategoryID = gc.GoodCategoryID
INNER JOIN DimTime tm ON ro.GoodTimeID = tm.GoodTimeID
WHERE dp.State = 'Italy' AND ds.State = 'Italy'
GROUP BY gc.GoodCategory, tm.Month, tm.Year;
```

The main point is that, in order to make your query is not a valid aggregate query, you need to use an aggregate function within the window function, like `SUM(SUM(ro.Income)) OVER (...)` instead of just `SUM(ro.Income) OVER(...)`, so you get a window sum over the previous *groups* of records.

Other notable points:

- *always* use explicit joins (with the `ON` keyword) rather than old-school, implicit joins (with commas in the `FROM` clause), whose syntax has fallen out of favor for *decades*
- `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is not needed; your window function has an `ORDER BY` clause so that's what it does anyway